# jQuery animate not working svg circle element

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have a svg in my html like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="31px" height="559px" viewBox="0 0 31 559" version="1.1">
    <title>pagination</title>
    <g id="svg-container" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="11-copy-6" transform="translate(-112.000000, -847.000000)">
            <g id="pagination" transform="translate(113.000000, 848.000000)">

                <circle id="inner" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="9.5"/>
                <circle id="outer" stroke="#FFFFFF" cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14.5"/>
                <circle id="outer-2" stroke="#FFFFFF" cx="14.5" cy="200.5" r="9.5"/>
                <circle id="outer-3" stroke="#FFFFFF" cx="14.5" cy="374.5" r="9.5"/>
                <circle id="outer-4" stroke="#FFFFFF" cx="14.5" cy="547.5" r="9.5"/>
                <path d="M14.5,29 L14.5,191" id="Line" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-linecap="square"/>
                <path d="M14.5,210.225038 L14.5,365.225038" id="Line-Copy" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-linecap="square"/>
                <path d="M14.5,384 L14.5,538.225038" id="Line-Copy-2" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-linecap="square"/>

            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I'm trying to change position of the circle with id inner, like so:

```
let x = $('circle#inner')
x.animate({top: '187px'}, 500)
```

But its not working, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery animate is for animating HTML elements. For SVG you have to try jQuery SVG plugin. Please follow the link - http://keith-wood.name/svg.html

It is possible without a plugin, but it involves a trick then. The issue is that x is not a css property but an attribute, and jQuery.animate only animates css properties. But you can use the step parameter to specify your own custom behavior for the animation.

foo is a non-existing property whose animating value we use in the step function.

```html
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#dice_1').animate(
        {'foo':200},
        {
            step: function(foo){
                 $(this).attr('x', foo);
            },
            duration: 2000
        }
    );
});
```